# FlatList and loading images when they are shown

Tags: react-native

I'd like to load images from items in a Flatlist, but only when they are visible.
I have a long list (well, technically a Sectionlist in the video I provide, but I'm currently experimenting with FlatList for my react native first app). There are 300+ items in my list and it seems everything is loaded when the FlatList appears. How can I approach [that result](https://vimeo.com/244446923)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `removeClippedSubviews={true}` in your `flatlist`.